# Angular elements with Angular routing

Tags: angular

I would like to use Angular routing in a component that's bootstrapped as a custom element. It appears that if I place several custom elements on a page, only the last element receives the router-outlet.

Here is the repo with [a sample on GitHub](https://github.com/popsovy/AngElmsTest)

I generated this sample project by:

- ng new (with routing)
- ng add @angular/elements
- changed to bootstrap via createCustomElement (my-el is the element name)
- changed TypeScript "target" to Es6
- changed Index.html to host two my-el elements

Do you know why only the last instance of my component has router-output and all other instances route to that element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you can have only one primary router outlet per module. (Primary outlet is the one with no name specified in the template)
I found this article helpful: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/

You can work around that by naming your outlets - but since you are using the same app components I think you will need something along those lines:

app.component.ts:

```
@Input() name: string;

getRouterLink(url: string): object {
    return { outlets: { primary: url, first: url, second: url } };
}
```

index.html

```
<my-el name="first"></my-el>
<my-el name="second"></my-el>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "page1", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "page1", component: Page1Component },
    { path: "page2", component: Page1Component },
    { outlet: "first", path: "page1", component: Page1Component },
    { outlet: "first", path: "page2", component: Page2Component },
    { outlet: "second", path: "page1", component: Page1Component },
    { outlet: "second", path: "page2", component: Page2Component }
];
```

app.component.html:

```
<h2><a href="#" [routerLink]="getRouterLink('page1')">Page1</a></h2>
<h2><a href="#" [routerLink]="getRouterLink('page2')">Page2</a></h2>
<ng-container *ngIf="name === 'first'">
    <router-outlet name="first"></router-outlet>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="name === 'second'">
    <router-outlet name="second"></router-outlet>
</ng-container>
```

This could be made nicer ofc but should be enough to illustrate the point.

I've tried binding router-outlet's 'name' dynamically (`<router-outlet [name]="name">`) so it's not wrapped in those ng-containers, but that's not possible since 'name' is an @Attribute and not an @Input of the router-outlet (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L50)